# Why document click listener triggers immediately?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to bind a click function to the document when open some menu via click.
The problem is that when trigger the first event 'click on the menu', the function attached to the document has been triggered by the same event and close the menu. How to solve that issue. My code is something like that:

```
$('#openMenu').bind('click touchend', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.openMobMenu').removeClass('openMobMenu');//Close All elements
    var _this=$('#headMenu')
    _this.addClass('openMobMenu');

    $(document).bind('click touchend',{elem:_this},hideElementMob);
});

// bind click event listner to the document
function hideElementMob(e){

    var th=e.data.elem;//Get the open element
    var target=$(e.target);//Get the clicked target

        //Check the target and close the element if need
    if(target.parents('.openMobMenu').length==0) { 
        th.removeClass('openMobMenu');//close the element if need
        //Unbind listner after closing the element
        $(document).unbind('click touchend');
    } 
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `bind` was superseeded. Use `on`.

Comment: You are binding a click event to the document every time you click to open the menu. It would be a better idea to check if you clicked on the `#openMenu` in your hideelement function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the close handler with a little delay:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $(document).bind('click touchend',{elem:_this},hideElementMob);
}, 10);
```

And as Jan Dvorak suggested, you should use .on() to attach events.

**UPDATE**
I realized I did not answer the whole question, so here is some improvement to the "*why does it behave like this*" part:

When the click event occurs on `#openMenu`, the associated handler is executed first. This binds a click event to the document body itself.
After this, the event gets bubbled, so the parents of the `#openMenu` also recieves a click event, and since `document.body` is a parent of the `#openMenu`, it also recieves a click event and closes the popup immediatley.

To cancel the event bubbling, you can also call `e.stopPropagation();` anywhere in your event handler. (maybe its a cleaner solution compared to setTimeout)

Comment: Thanks, that timeout do the job!